# R - cut2 versus quantile function

Tags: r, quantile, hmisc, quartile

Could anyone please tell me the difference between the quantile function in R and the cut2 function from the HMISC package?

I understand that the quantile has 9 different methods for specifying quartiles. However, when I use the function cut2(mydata, g = 4), the quartiles which are output do not correspond to any of the quantile function outputs.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the `cut2` helpfile:

> Function like cut but left endpoints are inclusive and labels are of
>   the form [lower, upper), except that last interval is [lower,upper].
>   If cuts are given, will by default make sure that cuts include entire
>   range of x.

So, `cut2` is basically `cut` with a few different defaults. Let's look at `cut` then.

From the `cut` helpfile:

> cut divides the range of x into intervals and codes the values in x
>   according to which interval they fall. The leftmost interval
>   corresponds to level one, the next leftmost to level two and so on.

From the `quantile` helpfile:

> The generic function quantile produces sample quantiles corresponding
>   to the given probabilities. The smallest observation corresponds to a
>   probability of 0 and the largest to a probability of 1.

**One cuts the range of `x`, the other cuts the "frequency" of `x`.**

An illustration:

```
out <- 0:100
out2 <- c(seq(0, 50, 0.001), 51:100)
```

Both have the same range. From 0 to 100.

```
levels(cut(out,4, include.lowest = T))
[1] "[-0.1,25]" "(25,50]"   "(50,75]"   "(75,100]" 
levels(cut(out2,4, include.lowest = T))
[1] "[-0.1,25]" "(25,50]"   "(50,75]"   "(75,100]"
```

But there are many more "datapoints" living in `out2`, in particular for values between 0 and 50. Therefore, they do not have the same frequencies along the range:

```
quantile(out)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
   0   25   50   75  100 
quantile(out2)
      0%      25%      50%      75%     100% 
  0.0000  12.5125  25.0250  37.5375 100.0000
```

This is the difference between `cut` and `quantile`.

The above example also shows you when both agree, namely in the case of uniform distributions. The sequence from 0 to 100, for instance, is evenly distributed on the range from 0 to 100. Here, both are basically identical.

To illustrate even further, consider:

```
outdf <- data.frame(out=out, cut=cut(out,4, include.lowest = T))
out2df <- data.frame(out=out2, cut=cut(out2,4, include.lowest = T))

table(outdf$cut)
[-0.1,25]   (25,50]   (50,75]  (75,100] 
       26        25        25        25 
table(out2df$cut)
[-0.1,25]   (25,50]   (50,75]  (75,100] 
    25001     25000        25        25
```

Here, you clearly see the different frequencies in each bin.

Comment: thank you for your well-explained answer - it helped a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help.